# How to print the current executing method name via an auxiliary method?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics, stack-frame

`ExecutingMethodName` is intended to print the method name of the caller. For example:

- `static void Main(string[] args){Auxiliary.ExecutingMethodName();}` should print Main.
- `static void Foo(){Auxiliary.ExecutingMethodName();}` should print Foo.

```
static class Auxiliary
{
    public static void ExecutingMethodName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new StackFrame(0).GetMethod().Name);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Auxiliary.ExecutingMethodName();// should print Main
    }
    static void Foo()
    {
        Auxiliary.ExecutingMethodName();// should print Foo
    }    
}
```

## Question

The current implementation above always print `ExecutingMethodName` that is not what I want. How to print the current executing method name via an auxiliary method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change 0 to 1 in stackframe call in your method  (`StackFrame(0)` is your currrent position in call stack and you need to go one step back):

```
public static void ExecutingMethodName()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to skip the first entry in the stack frame (which belongs to `ExecutingMethodName`):

```
public static void ExecutingMethodName()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead using something from the stackframe. Much cleaner way.

```
public static void ExecutingMethodName([CallerMemberName]string callerName= null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(callerName);
}
```

Comment: Voted up. Nice idea. What is the purpose of initializing `callerName=null`?

Comment: "You apply the CallerMemberName attribute to an optional parameter that has a default value. You must specify an explicit default value for the optional parameter. You can't apply this attribute to parameters that aren't specified as optional." from the MSDN link provided.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code. You have to use `StackFrame(1)`, `StackFrame(2)` will always be the `ExecutingMethodName`, actually you have to print the caller of `ExecutingMethodName`.

```
public static void ExecutingMethodName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
        }
```

You can refer [StackFrame Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws7f30w6(v=vs.110).aspx)

In C# 5 it has become more easy.

[CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)